# To auto-fill the values in textbox on edit button click and edit/update values in HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

To Edit/Update the displayed details of HTML form.

view.php

I have some output/display details as such-

```
  FirstName:  ABC  
  LastName:   PQR  
  Position:   Developer
  Gender:     Male
```

This is displayed in proper format in HTML bootstrap.

Now ,we want to edit/update this details ,that is onClick of button these fields should convert into textboxes with auto-fill of these same values as such-

```
         ------
Gender:   Male   <-in the textbox on edit/update click button. [For all fields]
         ------
```

We have tried this so far-

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label for="Telephone Number">Firstname :</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 f1">
            <?php echo $FirstName; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="fnane">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['FirstName'];?>">
        </div>


    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 f1">
            <label for="LastName">Lastname :</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <?php echo $LastName; ?>                                    
        </div>
        <div class="lname">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['LastName'];?>">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">

    <input type="button" id="candi_v_btn" name="candi_v_btn" value="Edit" class="btn2 btn-primary show" style="margin-left:348px"> <!--onClick="document.location.href='addcandidate.php'"-->
    </div>
```

And Jquery as:

```
(function() {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.fname').eq(0).hide();
$('.lname').eq(0).hide();
$('.pos').eq(0).hide();
$('.gen').eq(0).hide();

});


$(".show").click(function () {
$('.f1').eq(0).hide();
$('.fname').eq(0).show();
$('.lname').eq(0).show();
$('.pos').eq(0).show();
$('.gen').eq(0).show();
});
  })();
```

What we are getting from above codes is - Infront of output values blank textboxes are being displayed.

What we are getting is[image: Infront of output values blank textboxes are being displayed.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vinod...I was looking for this post from yesterday. I am too a learner of js.
You can try with this edits..use window.load() instead of document.ready() as-

```
(function () {
    $(window).load(function(){

    //Your code as written above.
    });
 })();
```

This works fine for me in fiddle.

Comment: @Roshan.I will try it and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

First, I noticed a few errors in the HTML, so those were cleaned up. That was part of the problem. One of those was the `class="fnane"` (should be `class="fname"`). Another was that the f1 class for the lastname text was in the wrong spot.

After those changes, I switched up a bit of the jquery function. I think it is functioning the way you are wanting, but let me know if not.  Here is the cleaned up code:

**EDIT:**  Adding **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1uu167ot/1/)** link.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label for="Firstname">Firstname :</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 f1">
            Testing 
        </div>
        <div class="fname">
            <input type="text" name="Firstname" class="form-control" value="Testing" />
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.row -->
</div><!-- /.form-group -->

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label for="LastName">Lastname:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 f1">
            McTesterson                                    
        </div>
        <div class="lname">
            <input type="text" name="Lastname" class="form-control" value="McTesterson" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.row -->
    <div class="btn-group">
        <input type="button" id="candi_v_btn" name="candi_v_btn" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary show" /> 
    </div><!-- /.btn-group -->
</div><!-- /.form-group -->
```

**JQUERY**

```
(function() {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.fname').hide();
        $('.lname').hide();
    });

    $(".show").click(function () {
        $('.f1').hide();
        $('.fname').show();
        $('.lname').show();
    });
})();
```

Hope this helps the cause.

**EDIT 2:** Adding **[another JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/nta0h8p6/1/)** that adjusts the JS a tad, and things still work.

Comment: @cfnerd..Thank you ..but on document.ready(function) the fname and lname are not hiding. Also when I click my edit button, the f1..should hide..its too not working...The output is as such -->FirstName: ABC & infront of it...the text box is being displayed with ABC values in it.

Comment: @cfnerd..See I have inserted an image to my question..Hope you will get now. Thank You. It on "edit button click" the info should be like this image.

Comment: @vinod I have added two JSFiddle links to show things are working as I believe you are wanting. Look at your HTML and compare it to mine.  Notice the comments at the beginning of my answer...you have a class on the wrong div, which will cause problems.

Comment: thank you! its Working fine in JSFiddle but its giving same problem through localhost.

Comment: Can you help us with this. When page is initialized the text boxes are still being displayed in front of values. the code works fine in Fiddle.Is it problem with document.ready() function? as we have more .JS scripts above Your JS code. 
I am posting my answer..please have a look...suggest the solution if any.

Answer (score 1):

It Worked, what the error was we were using document.ready() instead of window.load(). Thanks For all of your suggestions.

```
(function () {
    $(window).load(function(){

    $('.fname').hide();
     $('.lname').hide();
    $('.pos').hide();
    $('.gen').hide();
    });
 })();

    $(".show").click(function () {
        $('.f1').hide();
        $('.fname').show();
        $('.lname').show();
        $('.pos').show();
        $('.gen').show();
    });
)}();
```